# Filtering a list from a list in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I have a main list of ids (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

And I have a list of ids I want removed from the main list (2,5,8)

What's the easiest way of filtering these ids out of the main list in coldfusion?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the Replace function http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_m-r_32.html

Comment: No, replace searches for substrings, not whole list elements. Perhaps you meant [ReplaceList](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/functions_m-r_33.html)? Also, cflib.org is also good place to check for this sort of task http://cflib.org/udf/listRemoveList

Comment: Oops, Tom beat you to it ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ReplaceList:

```
<cfset l1 = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8">
<cfset L2 = "2,5,8">

<cfoutput>#ReplaceList(L1,L2,'')#</cfoutput>
```

This will leave you with extra commas which ColdFusion lists are ok with.  If you want to remove them then run them through the array functions:

```
<cfset l1 = "1,2,,3,4,5,6,7,8">
<cfset L2 = "2,5,8">
<cfset L3 = ArrayToList(ListToArray(ReplaceList(L1,L2,'')))>
<cfoutput>#L3#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Awesome, I did not know of this function. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An elegant solution is possible on CF 10+ and Railo 4+ via [Underscore.cfc's without function](http://russplaysguitar.github.io/UnderscoreCF/#without):

```
_ = new Underscore();// instantiate the library

// prepare the original list
origList = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
origArray = listToArray(origList);

// get a new array of values without 2, 5, or 8
newArray = _.without(origArray, [2, 5, 8]);// returns [1,3,4,6,7,9,10]
```

You can then use `arrayToList()` to convert back to a list, if necessary.

Note: I wrote Underscore.cfc